# How to read special characters in a string in java

Tags: java, string, special-characters, charat

I'm given a String & I need to find whether it contains any special character or not? I tried using `charAt()` and ASCII values.But it didn't work.Someone please help.Thanks in advance.

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    char c=s.charAt(i);
    if(65<=c<=90)
    {
        System.out.println("Valid");
    }
    else if(97<=c<=122)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid as it contains lower case letter");
        break;
    }
    else if(48<=c<=57)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid as it contains numbers");
        break;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid as it contains special characters");
}
```

Comment: Which characters are the "special characters". Or to be more specific: Which characters are considered "OK"?

Comment: "it didn't work" doesn't tell us what your code looked like, or the input, or the expected output, or the actual output. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Actually.. i want only the block letters. All others are considered as invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "asda®††∆˚∆asd121";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]", ""));
}
```

O/P :

```
®††∆˚∆
```

If the size after replacing is 0, then there were no special characters. You can update the regex with what you consider as *special*. :)

Comment: replaceAll is a function? how to use it? actually i'm new to java programming.

Comment: @Darpanjbora - Yes, it is a function. It takes a regex as input

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that something like this: `65<=c<=90` will not work in java. You can't chain compares!

You'll have to write something like this:

```
if (65 <= c && c <= 90)
```

Or to increase readability i'd suggest you to do something like this:

```
if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
```

Comment: OK. thats where the problem was. Thanks a lot. I didn't know that chain comparison is not possible in java. Thanks @parkerHalo.

Answer (score 1):

In Java `65<=c<=90` is not a valid comparison.

You'll need to write your conditions like this:

```
if (65<=c && c<=90) {
    ...
} else if (97<=c && c<=122) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. actually i didn't know that. thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringUtils : [isAllUpperCase](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAllUpperCase(java.lang.CharSequence))

Or else try something like this in case you want to check for each character.

```
public static boolean isUpperCase(String s)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        {
            if (!Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

}
```

Comment: ok. thanks a lot. :)